# Run-time error: *** glibc detected ***

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, glibc, realloc

I was experimenting random things to know more about malloc, realloc and free and how they behave when they are used together.

I will include the code and my idea what I was trying to do.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
   char *str;

   /* Initial memory allocation */
   str = (char *) malloc(15);
   strcpy(str, "63tczfqV4nqB2YnH9iFJbGvGyyDkvK341rrj0G0mo1PEYniOVHejVIFIQnJzHSSMRbuyGMCZ4M5HFMV4y1q4QgYqyxp2XkTjxaolKTkaw1r25S2Emz061tw1");
   printf("String = %s,  Address = %u\n", str, *str);

   /* Reallocating memory */
   str = (char *) realloc(str,16);
   strcat(str, "12345678");
   printf("String = %s,  Address = %u\n", str, *str);

   free(str);
   return 0;
}
```

#### I expected my code to behave like this:

1. I created a character-type memory pointer to point (at max) 15 bytes of memory using malloc.
2. Using that character pointer, I saved 120 characters using strcpy.
3. I resized my character pointer to now point (at max) 16 bytes.
4. I concatenated, using strcat, 8 more characters to that memory buffer which is already holding 120 characters.
5. Now, my character pointer should point to 128 characters and I tried to reproduce that, however, it failed for 128 characters (but printed the earlier 120 characters which was saved using strcpy).

The exact error was this:

```
 ***** glibc detected *** ./a.out: realloc(): invalid next size: 0x0000000001690010 *****
```

and the console hung on this, i.e., it never moved past *realloc* line I suppose?

Comment: Your code has **undefined behaviour**. You've `malloc`ed 15 characters of storage, and then `strcpy` over the limits of this allocation. Downvoted and voted to close.

Comment: So if I want to save 120 characters, I should rather use malloc(120) ?

I expected it to be 15 bytes (not 15 characters).

Comment: Your initial `malloc` **must** be at least the length of that string + 1 (1 for the terminating `'\0'`). In C, the size of allocation is in `char`s/bytes, which, in this case happens to be 8-bit. (The standard says: byte
addressable unit of data storage large enough to hold any member of the basic character set of the execution environment)

Comment: @Avineshwar: In that case you really should first read a C book and understand its contents. Learn how to walk before trying to run.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: Actually "byte" and `char` are synonyms in the standard. The width doesn't make a difference.

Comment: @Olaf I know, but then there are those who think that a "byte" is an "octet" :(

Comment: @Olaf I was having a thought process of reproducing certain conditions, however, I will fix it. Regarding your C suggestion, that's under consideration. This was just a jump in an attempt to understand malloc and free. Let me tell you, I did manage to understand that

Comment: Crushing a hamster will not help to understand by it behaves as it does. The same for programming, even more in a weakly types and insecure language like C.

Comment: @Olaf I did modifications for which I need an explanation.

str = (char *) malloc(15) is now str = (char *) malloc(120) str = (char *) realloc(str,16) is now str = (char *) realloc(str,127) strcat(str, "12345678") is now strcat(str, "123456781234567") I found that it works for strcat(str, "123456781234567") but not for this strcat(str, "1234567812345678") i.e., some kind of access violation. Why is that?

Comment: Comments are not for tutoring (well, questions/asnwers aren't neither). Just the standard note: Don't cast `void *` to pointers in C!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's look at the first two lines of your code:

```
str = (char *) malloc(15);
strcpy(str, "63tczfqV4nqB2YnH9iFJbGvGyyDkvK341rrj0G0mo1PEYniOVHejVIFIQnJzHSSMRbuyGMCZ4M5HFMV4y1q4QgYqyxp2XkTjxaolKTkaw1r25S2Emz061tw1");
```

At this point, you have broken the rules of the C language. `strcpy` will write past the end of `str` which causes undefined behavior.

Everything that happens after this point is kinda up in the air.

Comment: So if I want to save 120 characters, I should rather use malloc(120) ?

I expected it to be 15 bytes (not 15 characters).

Comment: @Avineshwar: A 120 character string (which is likely encoded in ASCII) will need 120+1 bytes of space. The extra byte is to mark the end of the string.

Comment: I just saw I didn't mentioned that. I am aware of that. Thank you for surfacing it. I am trying to modify the program, not exactly to understand how malloc, realloc and .free works but, also to understand how well I can reproduced my memory-related understand with respect to C.

There's a decent amount of unclarity right now I guess.

Comment: I did modifications for which I need an explanation.

str = (char *) malloc(15) is now str = (char *) malloc(120)

str = (char *) realloc(str,16) is now str = (char *) realloc(str,127)

strcat(str, "12345678") is now strcat(str, "123456781234567")

I found that it works for strcat(str, "123456781234567") but not for this strcat(str, "1234567812345678") i.e., some kind of access violation.

Why is that?

Comment: Your last string requires 17 bytes. A string literal needs one additional byte for the terminating null character.